# Put an Array in another Array

Tags: java

I have an Array for "Questions". Each entry contains the Country, the right answer and 3 wrong answers. I need to put these Questions in  several different arrays (i.e. QuizA, QuizB ... QuizN) in accordance with a variable. The code is:

I thought to do it with a switch case, but I might need to do it with a for loop as follows:

```
String quizDataA[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};

String quizDataB[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};

String quizDataC[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};
```

Something like

```
String Quizzes = {quizDataA, quizDataB, quizDataC}
```

and write a for loop as:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Quizzes.length; i++) {
            if (answerBtn==Quizzes[i]) {
                -----
                break;
            }
        }
```

AND....I have the selecction of the questions,

```
for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++){
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]); //Country
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]); //Right Answer
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]); //Choice1
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]); //Choice2
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]); //Choice3

        //Add tmpArray to quizArray
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);
    }

    showNextQuiz();
```

And I need to, first choose the category (QuizA, QuizB) in accordance with the variable CategoryId (is a String with "1", "2",.....etc), and if is 1 choose QuizA and after, make this for to get the question in it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the two dimensional arrays into a three dimensional array

```
String[][][] quizzes = { quizDataA, quizDataB, quizDataC };
```

You will have to iterate three times, once for the quiz name (A, B, C), once for the question number (three questions), and once for the number of answers in a question (four possible).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
    String quizDataA[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};

String quizDataB[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};

String quizDataC[][] = {
        {"China", "Beijing", "Jakarta", "Manila", "Stockholm"},
        {"India", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Bangkok", "Seoul"},
        {"Indonesia", "Jakarta", "Manila", "New Delhi", "Kuala Lumpur"}
};
String quizzes[][][] = { quizDataA, quizDataB, quizDataC };
for (String str[][] : quizzes)
{
  for( String str1[]: str)
  {
    for(String str2:str1)
    {
      if (answerBtn.equals(str2)) {
                -----
                break;
            }
    }
  }
}
```